# Nodes in Ascending Order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, class

I have a class named `Poly` that takes in a list of tuples and converts them into polynomials... now I'm running into some issues in my `insert` function and can't figure out how to order the information ascending based on power

**Current Output Based on Input:**

```
>>> i = [(2,3),(2,1),(3,4),(2,3),(3,1)]
>>> p = Poly(i)
>>> print(p)
'4x^3 + 2x + 3x + 3x^4'
```

**Expected Output:**

```
>>> i = [(2,3),(2,1),(3,4),(2,3),(3,1)]
>>> p = Poly(i)
>>> print(p)
'5x + 4x^3 + 3x^4'
```

The solution must have the lowest powers on the left and the highest powers on the right. So in ascending order.

**My Code:**

```
class Poly:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, coef, power, next):
            self._coef = coef
            self._power = power
            self._next = next
            

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self._head = None
        self._size = 0
        
        for elem in lst:
            self.insert(elem)

    def insert(self, tup):
        
        node = self.Node(tup[0], tup[1], None)
        if node._coef == 0:
            return 
        if self.isEmpty():
            self._head = node
            self._size += 1
            return
        
        if self._head._power == node._power:
            self._head._coef += node._coef
            self._size += 1
            return
                
        curr = self._head
                              
        while curr._next and node._power >= curr._next._power:
                    if node._power == curr._power:
                        curr._coef += node._coef
                        return
                    curr = curr._next        
                                          
        self._size += 1
        node._next = curr._next
        curr._next = node
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: For the code to be a [mre] we would need `Poly.insert`... Anyway your current `__add__` is only able to process polynoms having the same number of nodes of same power and in same order. As we cannot know what is done is `insert` we can only guess, but you should try to add on a paper sheet following your code `2x^1` and `3x^2` and see what happens...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I will add the insert function

Comment: Since your `insert` statement is already supposed to be handling duplicates, all you need to do is concatenate the two lists and create a new `Poly` from the combined list.

Comment: @TimRoberts that would work only issue is I need to add instances where tuples have the same power or tuple[1] is the same as the other tuple[1]

Comment: That's what I said; you are already supposed to be handling that, right?  Didn't the original requirement say you had to take `[(2,3),(1,3),(5,0)]` as `5 + 3x^3`?